# Finding Rank of Kernel/Matrix using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Basically I want to find the rank of a given kernel/matrix so that I can check whether it is separable or not?

Is there a function in OpenCV to find the rank of a kernel?

If I'm correct, we can use the compute method of svd class to find the singular values, but after that how do we calculate the rank? The below is the code I used.

```
double k = 3;
float kdata[] = {2,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0};
Mat kernel(k,k,CV_32F, kdata);
Mat s,u,v;
SVD::compute(kernel,s,u,v);
```

Comment: The rank of the matrix "equals the number of non-zero singular values". See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11548343/3926689) answer.

Comment: So how exactly do I access the data or elements of a mat object so that I can count the number of non-zero singular values? And which variable(code is in question posted) should I be accessing?

Comment: Use `mat.at<T>(row, col)` along the diagonal of `s`. The diagonal entries of `s` are known as the singular values of your matrix `kernel`.

Comment: This is the code I'm using-

Comment: This is the code I'm using-                                                                                                for(int i = 0; i < s.rows; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < s.cols; j++)
        cout<<s.at<double>(i,j)<<endl;

    }                                                                                                                                                                                 Output- 0.0078125
5.26354e-315
2.122e-314
So is the rank of my matrix  3 then?

Answer (score 0):

When we use the compute method of SVD class, we are basically calculating singular value decomposition of a  matrix and the singular values are calculated and stored in the first parameter i.e variable 's'.

Now to find the rank of matrix, all we have to do is count the number of non-zero values in variable 's'.

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.rows; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < s.cols; j++)
    {
      if( s.at<float>(i,j) != 0)
        count++;
    }
}
cout<<count<<endl;
```

'Count' variable stores our rank. Now if rank is 1, then the filter is separable. If it is more than 1, it is not separable.

I want to thank Frik for helping me reach to the answer.