# How to calculate matrix rank in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, matrix, rank, svd

I have a non square matrix in OpenCV.
I want to calculate it's rank.
I understood you need to do SVD decomposition and count the rows or on one of the parts of it? Not sure...
I could really use code example in OpenCV(C/C++), because there is too much room for me to make errors...
I found this thread... [opencv calculate matrix rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548282/opencv-calculate-matrix-rank)

But it has no code example...

So if there is no code example maybe you could explain the steps to find the rank of a non square matrix in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11548343/5008845), you need to find the number of non-zero singular value. So, first find the singular values with SVD decomposition, and then count the number of non zero values. You may need to apply a small threshold to account for numeric errors:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Your matrix
    Mat1d M = (Mat1d(4,5) <<    1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
                                0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                0, 2, 0, 0, 0);

    // Compute SVD
    Mat1d w, u, vt;
    SVD::compute(M, w, u, vt);

    // w is the matrix of singular values
    // Find non zero singular values.

    // Use a small threshold to account for numeric errors
    Mat1b nonZeroSingularValues = w > 0.0001;

    // Count the number of non zero
    int rank = countNonZero(nonZeroSingularValues);

    return 0;
}
```